# How to Maximise width on a UserControl plugin for a WinForms application

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, windows-forms-designer

I'm working on a plugin for a third-party application, building in WinForms. My plugin gets added to a pane in the host application, and on the left is a sizeable pane with a draggable divider between that and mine.

How can I make my UserControl maximise the space to which it has been added? Each time I run the application my UserControl is at the design-time width.

I've tried

```
this.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
```

But this seems to assign my UserControl the full width of the window, ignoring the sizeable pane on the left, and consequently a horizontal scrollbar is added.

I've also added

```
Width = Parent.Width;
```

in the constructor, but `Parent` is null.

And if I set

```
AutoSize = true;
```

the UserControl still maintains the design-time dimensions, unless I set `AutoSizeMode = GrowAndShrink`, in which case the control doesn't appear - I suspect it as shrunk to 0px by 0px.

Is this a problem I can do anything about or am I at the mercy of how the hosting application adds my UserControl?

Comment: You can set the location and size to fill the space and anchor all four sides

Comment: "DockStyle.Fill" is correct and is the same as Anchoring to all four sides. The control needs to be within a parent control that resizes when the divider is moved.

Comment: @WithoutHaste So if I've set `Dock.Fill` and it's not filling the available space does this indicate that the parent control is not going to play nicely with my control when it comes to sizing? In other words, does this suggest that there's nothing I can do?

Comment: @awj Is there a resize event in the third-party control that you can subscribe to?

Comment: @WithoutHaste No, no events. The control doesn't have to derive from anything other than UserControl.